# input function argument changes after calling this function

Tags: c#

I'm using C#
I have a function:

```
public double[] PerformBeeDance(double[] vector, double r) {
            int index = rand.Next(0, vector.Length);
            double[] result = vector;
            result[index] = vector[index] + rand.NextDouble() * r;
            return result;
        }
```

I put `bees[i].Position` to this function and after calling it:

```
newbee.Position = PerformBeeDance(bees[i].Position, r);
```

`bees[i].Position` is changing with `newbee.Position` but it should stay the same.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Where does `newbee` come from? Anyway arrays are passed by reference. You _are_ updating `bees[i].Position`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double[]` is a ReferenceType, So although it is passed as a copy, the copy is only of the reference, which both refer the same instance.

**EDIT**

possible solution As @RaymondChen pointed out in a comment, is `Array.Clone`:

```
public double[] PerformBeeDance(double[] vector, double r)
{
    int index = rand.Next(0, vector.Length);
    double[] result = vector.Clone();
    result[index] = vector[index] + rand.NextDouble() * r;
    return result;
}
```

or make the copy in caller code:

```
newbee.Position = PerformBeeDance(bees[i].Position.Clone(), r);
```

Comment: Use `Array.Clone` to make a new copy.